# m2m_changed : int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'set'

Tags: python, django

i want to to update field whenever an instance been created i tried signals but it seems complicate to ManyToManyField

```
def update_m2m(sender,instance,*args,**kwargs):

    if kwargs.get("pk_set"):
         pk = kwargs.get("pk_set")
         Imei.objects.filter(pk=pk).update(active=False)
     #and also tried this but still not work 
     #Imei.objects.filter(pk=instance.id).update(active=False)
m2m_changed.connect(update_m2m,sender=SelectMobile.imei.through)
```

and also tried this

```
def update_m2m(sender,instance,*args,**kwargs):

    if kwargs.get("pk_set") and kwargs.get("action") == "post_add":
         pk = kwargs.get("pk_set")
         Imei.objects.filter(pk=pk).update(active=False)
m2m_changed.connect(update_m2m,sender=SelectMobile.imei.through)
```

but raised this error:

> int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'set'

not updated , and print nothing

this models.py

```
class SelectMobile(models.Model):
    #others
    imei = models.ManyToManyField(Imei)

class Imei(models.Model):
    imei = models.CharField(max_length=15,verbose_name='IMEI',unique=True)
    mobile = models.ForeignKey(MobileStorage,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

i want to update active field in Imei model when SelectMobile created !?

is there something i've missed ?thanks for helping

Comment: Imei.objects.filter(pk__in=kwargs.get('pk_set')).update(active=False)

Comment: thanks alot , worked , you can write the answer and i will accept